# Beginner Question on Understanding Linear Classifier

Tags: image-classification, multilabel-classification, bias, linear-algebra, matrix

I have been trying to understand the math behind Linear classifier for images and I'm hitting a roadblock to understanding this image below:

[image]

I can to some extent agree that we stretch the pixels into a column, but I do not understand why we do so? Secondly, what is that weights matrix? How is it choosen and why it is a 3x4 Matrix? Finally, how are the values for the bias is choosen?

Could someone please help me out?

EDIT: I think, I'm having a basic understanding of the weight matrix and here it goes:

The rows in the weights Matrix are Red, Green and Blue and the first element in the first row and first column indicates the red intensity of the first pixel, the second element in the first row and second column indicates the red intensity of the second pixel. Is this correct?

What I now do not understand is the why part of why we have to do this? Can someone give me a mathematical reasoning as to why I have to do such a stretching the pixel and multiply that by the weights?

Comment: There's no special reason behind stretching the pixels into a column. As we consider each image as a sample, we wish to represent each image as a vector. This relates with the concept of a random vector which is a 1D collection of random variables placed inside a vector,

$$
X = [ X_1 , X_2 , ... , X_n ]
$$

This gives us a compact representation for our dataset. Each $X_i$ represents the value of a particular pixel that can be taken in all images of our dataset.

Comment: I'm still not getting your explanation. You mean to say the pixels become our feature vector with each image having n pixels resulting in a 1D vector containing the image pixels as features?

Comment: Yes, each pixel is considered as a feature.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is safe to state that the a $3\times 4$ matrix is used for ease of notation, in actuality the picture will for example be a $400 \times 300$ matrix of pixel values. In this case it would be stretched to a single vector with $400 \cdot 300 = 120\ 000$ values. In this case you would then have a $3 \times 120\ 000$ matrix (which is quite hard to fit on a page).

Each row of the matrix is chosen in such a way that when you multiply the row with this large column vector (which represents the picture of the cat) you get a high value when the picture looks like a cat but a low score if it doesn't. For example let's assume that for all cat pictures the first pixel has a very high value, then the first value at position $(1,1)$ of the weight matrix will have a high value.

I do not think the red/blue/green colors have any meaning here, the weight matrix could have additional columns representing camel, moose, duck, ...